# WSDL handling practices for external service

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I have a project where it's dependent on Oracle Hosted web services (not WCF). I have a copy of the WSDLs for the services and their correlated XSDs.

What is the proper way of generating the proxies and datacontract assembly for this?

I started with

```
XSD.exe /c /language:CS user.xsd
```

For each of my xsds. This generate a bunch of class objects with shared type violations (same object in all of the classes) so I pruned all the duplicates so they had single declarations.

Then built that assembly with only my classes files "datacontracts.dll"

Then I generated my service clients

```
svcutil.exe user.wsdl /n*:SomeNameSpace /r:datacontracts.dll /noconfig
```

But this didn't really seem to give what i want since it still caused all of the duplication of the classes inside the service clients.

Inside the classes generated from the XSDs I did notice each class definition had

```
[XmlType(Namespace = "urn:/crmondemand/xml/...")]
```

Do I  need to place that attribute the way it shows up on repeated classes once for each class inside where I have made it be the singular class? So that I would have

```
[XmlType(Namespace = "urn:/crmondemand/xml/user")]
[XmlType(Namespace = "urn:/crmondemand/xml/campaign")]
[XmlType(Namespace = "urn:/crmondemand/xml/lead")]
public class SharedClass
```

Or am I approaching this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a warning... you probably know - but in case you don't I'd certainly say that pruning generated code is a recipe for disaster...

As for reusing types - I myself have never found the Microsoft stack to be particularly good in this regard... there are two lines of thought though... One says that "all web services" - by their very nature - are separate entities... As such - all code that is emitted is only valid inside that one web service.

I find this to be incredibly short sighted. I much prefer to reuse any types I can... However with .NET I found this to be very hard...  The closest thing I've found was a tool called WSCF.  It does some nice things that I really like such as emitting separate cs files for each class.  This makes "overwriting" them from some other source- as long as the source generates serializble equivalents - quite easy...

The problem I had with WSCF (classic mind you) is that it doesn't do "xml namespace" to "c# namespace" mapping... I actually had to add that to the tool myself... (I tried to commit it back to the project but never heard back sadly)

So I would tell you to try out WSCF.blue (targets WCF) or look into WCF classic.  You can find them both on codeplex.

Hope that helps you out..

Comment: "dependent on Oracle Hosted web services (not WCF)" if i had control over the code that i could replace the web service with WCF I'd probably just be using NHibernate anyway.

Comment: I'll go for this answer since it really just acknowledges web services that are not WCF suck and the problem is the web service isn't WCF.

Comment: well thanks Chris - but I'm actually advocating that Every Microsoft stack for web services I've used "sucks" in this regard (for the most part though - I like MS's stack)... 

I really encourage you look into WSCF.Blue... I think it can do what you're looking for - or at least get you a lot closer... (I use it on every project I deal with in .NET) Where you'll find the biggest 'bang' for your buck is the option to 'emit in separate files'... Then - even if the EXACT same class is emitted more than once it just gets overwritten ... (assuming they aren't 'actual' name clashes)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the following work as expected?

```
svcutil *.wsdl *.xsd /language:C#
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this worked as expected, I got a whole bunch of different classes for same names like Account1 Account2 etc. It's probably their XSD's messed up =/